# Google analytics API: what is the difference between a 'service application' and an 'installed application'

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

In the Google Analytics API documentation you can view the API in Python for a 'Service application' and an 'Installed application'. What is the difference between these two? The option for Python for a 'Web application' is not available... why is this?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: I'm looking to build and application where people can connect their google analytics accounts online and then they will get sent an email with a report in it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

service application https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount.
installed application https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#installed.

basically it's saying **service application** is server to server communication and **installed application** is your mobile/web apps making request to GA through oauth.

Comment: Thank you for the answer